# Custom install script like fantastico or softaculous

Tags: php, joomla, installation

I need a php installation script for a Joomla (or whatever) site, like fantastico or softaculous.

The problem is, I don't need a standard installation. I want to add some extensions and add some settings to the installation.

Where can I find a good base for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think softaculous itself has custom scripts support :
http://demo.softaculous.com/index.php?act=customscripts

http://www.softaculous.com/docs/api

Answer (score 1):

Softaculous also supports custom scripts support, you can try that.
Otherwise, just create a simple PHP script which just copies your Joomla script into a directory with preconfigured configuration files (Like wordpress has wp-config.php). and write a script to import database which joomla provides. This is what every Script installer does.
Let me know if you need further info.